# CSS does not work properly from network drive (html and css both in the same drive)

Tags: html, css, network-drive

I have used html+CSS to create a Navigation bar. Everything works well when I put the HTML and CSS in my 'Documents' folder, but it's not working when it's placed in the 'Network' folder. CSS style is not found when opened via IE9. It is fine on chrome.
Does anyone know the reason?

the HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">  
        <title>Projects</title>  
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="Index.css"/>

  </head>

  <body> 

    <!-- Navigation Bar --> 
        <nav id="topNav">  
                <ul>  
                    <li><a href="index.html" title="A">A</a></li>  
                <li>  
                    <a href="Projects-Main.html" title="Projects">Projects</a>
                    <ul>    
                        <li><a href="Projects-A.html" title="A">A</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="Projects-B.html" title="B">B</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="Projects-C.html" title="C">C</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="Projects-D.html" title="D">D</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="Projects-E.html" title="E">E</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="Projects-F.html" title="F">F</a></li> 
                        <li><a href="Projects-G.html" title="G">G</a></li> 
                        <li class="last"><a href="Projects-H" title="H">H</a></li>  
                    </ul>                  
                </li> 
                <li><a href="Services.html" title="Nav Link 1">Sevices</a> 
                    <ul>    
                        <li><a href="Services.html" title="AA">AA</a></li>  
                        <li><a href="Services.html" title="BB">BB</a></li>  
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">Contacts</a></li>  

        </nav> 
    <!-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------->

     </body>
</html>
```

The CSS is:

```
h1 { font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
     font-size: 120%;
     font-style: italic;
     text-decoration:underline;}


 /*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*Navigation Bar*/

nav { 
    display:block; 
    font:16px arie, Sans-serif ;
    border-top:2px solid ; 
    border-bottom:2px solid; 
    border-color:#F2F2F2;
    width:400px;
    float:right;
    margin: 35px 30px 0px 0px;
    z-index:10;}  
 nav ul {padding:0; margin:0; }

 nav li {position:relative; float:right; list-style-type:none; }
 nav ul:after { content:"."; display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }

 nav li a { display:block; padding:8px 20px; ; color:#8E8E8E; text-decoration:none;}
 nav li a:focus { outline:none; text-decoration:underline; }  

 nav ul ul { display:none; width:100%; position:absolute; right:0; background:#F2F2F2; text-align: right}


 nav ul ul li { float:none; border:solid #FFF 1px;  }
 nav ul ul a { padding:5px 10px;font-size:16px; } 
 nav ul ul a:hover { background-color:#555; }
```

Comment: I have same issue in IE11.666. The inline css styles does not apply. Chrome works well. It is probably some default security setting.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so I'll need to make a whole answer for this...
Have you tried making absolutely sure of that "index.css" exists in the same folder as your other file? I tried this, and it works properly for me in all browser. Have you doubled checked that it really is a .css file, and that the name is correct?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a slash in the css reference:

```
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"  href="/Index.css"/>
```

Comment: sorry, but this is wrong. A relative url starting withou slash or ./ an a serverabsolute path with a slash. See section 4.2 of the rfc: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt